# Multiple comparisons in each row

Tags: spss

On SPSS, I have a spreadsheet with over 6000 people on it. Each person has taken a test at least two times and has at least two results for the same test. Some people have taken the  test more than twice. Is it possible for SPSS to see if the two tests are within 6 months and if they are include the results of those tests next to the person and delete all other results?

**Structure of the data**

```
PersonNo  Test Date  Test Result  Test Date 2  Test result 2, Test Date 3, Test result 3
PersonNo 512, 23-Aug-18, 65, 22-May-18, 72
```

**Problem**

```
PersonNo 98432, 09-Feb-18, 74, 06-Nov-18, 76, 10-Aug-18, 67
PersonNo 91203, 10-Dec-18, 75, 10-Sep-18, 65
PersonNo 75432, 01-Jan-18, 65, 01-Dec-18, 65
```

**How I want it**

```
PersonNo 98432, 09-Feb-18, 74, 10-Aug-18, 67
PersonNo 91203, 10-Dec-18, 75, 10-Sep-18, 65
```

*Person No 75432 removed as they dont have two test results within 6 months*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you are describing is certainly possible (probably simple enough too), but you have to help us help you: Please edit your question to include a description of the structure of your data, a sample of the data with a demonstration of the problem, and a sample of the desired output. [Go here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to read more about asking good questions (which helps in getting good answers!).

Comment: Hi thanks. I have tried to improve the formatting of the question. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: a little more clarification - you want to compare all possible pairs of tests in every line? do you want to get rid just of line that don't meet the condition? in your example it seems you also want to get rid of specific tests that aren't part of such a pair

Comment: Hi Thanks. Yeah I want to see if there are any pairs of tests results that are within 6 months. If they are none I want the person to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

To see which tests were taken within 6 months of the `TestDate` variable you can use `DATEDIFF(date1, date2, units)`.  Since it's unclear how many TestDate fields you have, you may want to reorder your variables to use the VECTOR command to loop through them.

```
* assumes there are up to 11 tests each respondent may have taken.
VECTOR nextTestDate = TestDate2 TO TestDate 11 .
VECTOR nextTestResult = TestResult2 TO TestResult11 .
LOOP #i = 1 TO 10 .
* if not within 6 months then set date & result to sysmis .
DO IF (DATEDIFF(TestDate, nextTestDate(#i), 'days') > 182) .
  RECODE nextTestDate(#i) nextTestResult(#i) (ELSE = SYSMIS) .
END IF .
END LOOP .
EXE .
```

You don't need to do this within `VECTOR` if you only have a couple of TestDate fields to check.  From here you can delete any variables that no longer have any data in them (easily checked using DESC TestResult2 TO TestResult11).

Comment: That's a nice solution, but not sure yet if the OP wants to compare each test to the first test, as you did, or all possible pairs (in that case you'll need another loop, and then you cant remove a test until you've compared it to all other tests...).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As eli said, I need to have any pairs of results which are within 6 months of each other.

Comment: @eli-k Ah, yes - it looks like you were right about OP's requirements.  Solution above will only work when comparing against first test date.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a double loop and multiple comparisons, I suggest a restructure which enables sorting and comparison of only consecutive tests.

First I'm creating a small fake data to demonstrate on:

```
data list free/PersonNo (f6)   date1(Date11) score1(f3)    Date2(date11) score2 (f3)     Date3 (date11) score3(f3)   Date4 (date11) score4(f3).
begin data
98432, 09-Feb-18, 74, 06-Nov-18, 76, 10-Aug-18, 67, ,
91203, 10-Dec-18, 75, 10-Sep-18, 65, , , ,
75432, 01-Jan-18, 65, 01-Dec-18, 65, , , ,
12345, 19-Mar-18, 74, 26-Dec-19, 55, 10-Aug-18, 81, 19-Feb-19, 77
end data.
```

Now for the actual task:

```
* first step - restructuring to long format.

varstocases /make date from date1 date2 date3 date4/make score from score1 score2 score3 score4.

* now it is possible to sort by test date, compare the dates and keep only the relevant ones.

sort cases by PersonNo date.
if $casenum>1 and PersonNo=lag(PersonNo) cond=DATEDIFF(date, lag(date), 'days') < 182.
create cond2=lead(cond,1).
select if cond or cond2.
exe.

* At this point you have only the relevant persons and tests left. 
You might continue your analysis in this structure, 
but if you want the following code gets you back to the original structure.

compute ind=1.
if $casenum>1 and PersonNo=lag(PersonNo) ind=lag(ind)+1.
format ind(f1).
casestovars /id=PersonNo /index=ind /drop cond cond2 /groupby=index /separator="".
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Where would I put this in SPSS?

Comment: open a new syntax window (File -> New -> Syntax), and paste it there. Please [learn to use syntax](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-syntax-beginners-tutorial/) - this is the only way to get anything serious done in SPSS